# How to access a KEGG entry without specifying the organism using bioservices?

Tags: python, web-services, bioservices

I try to access [KEGG](http://www.genome.jp/kegg/) via [bioservices](https://pythonhosted.org/bioservices/kegg_tutorial.html) to get certain information about a list of genes. Problem is that I do not know beforehand to which organism the individual genes belong; in my list can be a lot of genes that all belong to different organisms. My problem is that I do not know how to retrieve the desired information about the genes without specifying the organism.

To give an example:

```
gene_list = ['YMR293C', 'b3640']
```

The [first gene](http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?sce:YMR293C) belongs to yeast, while the [second one](http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?eco:b3640) belongs to E.coli.

If I now try:

```
from bioservices import *
kegg_con = KEGG()
res = kegg_con.get('b3640', parse=True)['NAME']
```

I end up with a `TypeError` since

```
kegg_con.get('b3640', parse=True)
```

does not return a dictionary but just a number (since I do not specify the organism it belongs to). That works, however, when I specify the organism (here it is `eco` which stands for E.coli):

```
kegg_con.get('eco:b3640', parse=True)['NAME']
```

returns

```
[u'dut']
```

which is correct as one can see [here](http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?eco:b3640):

[image]

I then tried to get the information about the associated organism by using [find](https://pythonhosted.org/bioservices/references.html#bioservices.kegg.KEGG.find). That works fine for `YMR293C` but fails for `b3640`:

```
kegg_con.find('genes', 'YMR293C')
```

returns

> u'sce:YMR293C\tHER2, GEP6, QRS1, RRG6; glutamyl-tRNA(Gln)
>   amidotransferase subunit HER2 (EC:6.3.5.7); K02433
>   aspartyl-tRNA(Asn)/glutamyl-tRNA(Gln) amidotransferase subunit A
>   [EC:6.3.5.6 6.3.5.7]\ncal:CaO19.11438\tlikely amidase similar to S.
>   cerevisiae YMR293C mitochondrial putative glutamyl-tRNA
>   amidotransferase\ncal:CaO19.3956\tlikely amidase similar to S.
>   cerevisiae YMR293C mitochondrial putative glutamyl-tRNA
>   amidotransferase; K02433 aspartyl-tRNA(Asn)/glutamyl-tRNA(Gln)
>   amidotransferase subunit A [EC:6.3.5.6 6.3.5.7]\n'

from which I can easily extract the required information (in this case: `sce:YMR293C`), however, when I run

```
 kegg_con.find('genes', 'b3640')
```

I get

> u'cnb:CNBB3640\thypothetical protein; K06316 oligosaccharide
>   translocation protein RFT1\ncgi:CGB_B3640C\thypothetical
>   protein\neco:b3640\tdut; deoxyuridinetriphosphatase (EC:3.6.1.23);
>   K01520 dUTP pyrophosphatase [EC:3.6.1.23]\nsea:SeAg_B3640\tbfd;
>   bacterioferritin-associated ferredoxin; K02192
>   bacterioferritin-associated ferredoxin\nyps:YPTB3640\tconserved
>   hypothetical protein\nreu:Reut_B3640\tconserved hypothetical
>   protein\nbbr:BB3640\tphage-related exported
>   protein\nmag:amb3640\thypothetical
>   protein\nbcg:BCG9842_B3640\tflagellar hook-associated protein; K02407
>   flagellar hook-associated protein 2\ncbi:CLJ_B3640\tconserved
>   hypothetical protein; K09963 uncharacterized
>   protein\nmmo:MMOB3640\thypothetical protein\nmbo:Mb3640c\tftsH;
>   membrane-bound protease FTSH (cell division protein) (EC:3.4.24.-);
>   K03798 cell division protease FtsH [EC:3.4.24.-]\n'

which does not provide the information about E.coli.

My questions are therefore:

1) Is there a way so that I can access the information about a gene just based on its gene ID **without** specifying the organism it belongs to?

2) What would be the best way to retrieve the information to which organism the gene belongs? And why does `find` fail when I search for the E.coli gene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of the find() method is a pure string that is not easy to read but I believe the information you are looking for is in the output. On the third line, you can see:

```
eco:b3640
```

Now, I am not sure if the output format from KEGG is always having the same structure. If so, assuming the line of interest is the third one, you could use:

```
res = kegg_con.find('genes', 'b3640') 
orgnanism = res.split("\n")[2].split()[0].split(":")[0]
```

You can further check it is a valid orgnanism as follows:

```
assert organism in kegg_con.organismIds
```

To be on the safe side, you could search for the identifier in the string (rather than taking the third line):

```
[x for x in res.split() if "b3640" in x]
```

Hopes it helps

TC, the main author of bioservices

Comment: Thanks a lot for the immediate reply (upvoted)! Seems that the output format is not always the same (see the yeast example) but the list comprehension works fine. I'll probably add a few more questions over the next days/weeks, so please check the `bioservices` tag from time to time :)

Comment: I added another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742075/how-to-retrieve-reaction-ids-for-a-certain-organism-from-kegg). Would be great if you could take a look, thanks!